# ¿Es correcto usar "girarse" para referirse a "darse la vuelta"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

El otro día recordé una conversación de hace tiempo en el que una señora mayor (española) comentaba que actualmente la genten dice cosas como:

> **Gírate** para que te vea la espalda

Cuando, según ella, lo correcto sería decir

> **Date la vuelta** para que te vea la espalda

Es decir, que es incorrecto usar "girarse" para indicar el acto de "darse la vuelta", hacer un giro sobre el propio eje.

He estado buscando las definiciones en la RAE pero no encuentro referencias al respecto. ¿A alguien le consta algo al respecto?

Comment: No veo porque no ha de ser correcto. La RAE define "girar" como "dar vuelta (sobre un eje)" por lo tanto "Date la vuelta" es sinónimo de "Gírate".  Definición y sinónimo escritos usando exactamente los mismos verbos de la RAE. http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=S5158pHzGDXX2lwRVqXv

Comment: En vez de verlo incorrecto, lo veo poco usado en realidad. No sé si se usa más en otros países, pero si me dijeran *gírate*, entendería perfectamente que alude a *date vuelta*. Probablemente lo califican como incorrecto debido a su no uso, pero no implica que lo sea en realidad. Puede ser poco usado, pero no está incorrecto. Quizás la otra manera, más natural, podría ser decir *gira tu cuerpo*, pero la verdad no veo que esté mal.

Comment: Adicionalmente a mi comentario anterior quiero agregar que lo más común en Colombia es decir "voltéate".....otro sinónimo de "gírate". Lo que tiene muy poco uso (casi nulo) es "date vuelta"

Comment: @DGaleano Curioso. En Chile usamos mucho *date vuelta.*

Comment: @Subjunctive, ¿_date vuelta_ sin "la"? Caramba, esto en España suena rarísimo

Comment: @fedorqui Sí. Se usa demasiado acá.

Comment: En Aragón, al menos, he oído usar *gírate* con este sentido con frecuencia. Incluso *gírate del revés* o *gírate de frente* para expresar la posición en que queremos que quede la persona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La RAE define "girar" como "dar vuelta (sobre un eje)" por lo tanto "Date la vuelta" es sinónimo de "Gírate". Tanto la definición como el sinónimo están escritos usando exactamente los mismos verbos en la definición #4 este enlace de la RAE. http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=S5158pHzGDXX2lwRVqXv

De los comentarios podemos además decir que en Chile y Colombia usan `date vuelta` sin el artículo "la", aunque en Colombia es más frecuente `voltéate`. Gírate también se escucha frecuentemente en España en la región de Aragón.

Creo que podemos concluir que es perfectamente correcto usar la frase

> **Gírate** para que te vea la espalda

Answer (score 1):

El hecho de que existan expresiones como "la situación tomó un giro de 180 grados" implica que un giro no tiene por qué ser una revolución completa, al contrario de lo que esta señora quería dar a entender.