# girar vs girarse

Tags: reflexivos

On the [girar](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/girar) page of SpanishDict they have two examples of it's use: "to turn oneself". But one is reflexive and the other is not. Are both examples correct, and if so, when is a reflexive pronoun not needed?

girar

INTRANSITIVE VERB

7. (to turn one's body)
   a. to turn around

¡Todavía no gires! No he terminado de envolver tu regalo. (Don't turn around yet! I haven't finished wrapping your present.)

girarse

REFLEXIVE VERB

8. (to turn one's body)
   a. to turn around

¡Gírate y no mires atrás! (Turn around and don't look back!)

Comment: I would not use that site to learn Spanish I would buy a decent bilingual dictionary and put it on my computer. Like Harrap's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both "girar" and the pronominal "girarse" are correct to mean "turn around". However, with "girar" alone it might be the case that the person is in a vehicle.

- ¡Todavía no gires! No he terminado de envolver tu regalo. (Don't turn around yet. I haven't finished wrapping up your gift yet.)
- ¡Todavía no gires! Debes seguir derecho dos cuadras más. (Don't turn yet. You should go two more blocks straight ahead.)

I find the pronominal form to be usual in the imperative but rather weird in other tensed forms, where I'd tend to use "girar" or "darse vuelta":

- Giró / Se dio vuelta para que le viera la cara. (He turned around so I could see his face.)

Comment: Thank you for that. The use of girar alone in cases in a vehicle is interesting. I guess I still don't understand though why the first example wouldn't be reflexive (assuming they're not in a car). Similarly, why in the last example I'm confused why it wouldn't be "Se giró para que la viera la cara"?

Comment: I think you have found perhaps the only verb in Spanish that can be used both intransitively and reflexively with the same meaning. There are other verbs like caer/caerse, tropezar/tropezarse, etc. where the pronominal is quasi- but not a true reflexive. As I said at the beginning, intransitive "girar" and pronominal "girarse" can both be used to mean "turn (your own body) around". I have found a similar question here: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15716/es-correcto-usar-girarse-para-referirse-a-darse-la-vuelta.

Comment: As you can read in that other thread, just like me other speakers also find "girarse" unusual in most tenses and will tend to use "girar" or "darse vuelta".

Answer (score -1):

*¡Todavía no te gires! No he terminado de envolver tu regalo.*

Las siguientes son las acepciones que puedes encontrar en el verbo girar, algunas de ellas pueden ser utilizadas igualmente con el pronominal "girarse" y pueden servirte algunos ejemplos que he añadido.

**Girar**

Del lat. gyrāre.

- 1. tr. Mover una figura o un objeto alrededor de un punto o de un eje. **Gíralo hacia la ventana por favor.** **Gírame con los ojos vendados mirando al mar**.
- 2. tr. Enviar dinero por giro postal, telegráfico, etc. **¡Mamá Gírame el dinero de este mes!**
- 3. tr. Com. Expedir libranzas, talones, letras de cambio u otras órdenes de pago. Girar una letra. **¡Por favor gírame un cheque si no tienes dinero en efectivo!**, **Me giro un talón a noventa días**.
- 4. intr. Dicho de una cosa: Dar vueltas sobre un eje o en torno a un punto.
     **¡Gíralo!, Gíralo más de prisa!** **¡Como me gires tanto me voy a marear!.**
- 5. intr. Dicho de una conversación, de un negocio o de algo similar: Desarrollarse en torno a un tema dado. "El tema gira sobre los desiertos que existen en el mundo".
- 6. intr. Desviarse o cambiar con respecto a la dirección inicial. La calle gira a la derecha. **Gírate para que te vea la cara** (Darse la vuelta). **El se giro bruscamente**.
- 7. intr. Com. Hacer las operaciones mercantiles de una empresa. "Desde que llego Roberto la empresa ha dado un giro de 180 grados".